# Passing a parameter on a Web API Get method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This is my `api controller` method to get a list of items filtered by a user id.

```
public IEnumerable<MyItemListItemDTO> Get(int userId)
```

When calling the method from the client why won't `/MyItems/Get/11` work and `/MyItems/Get?userId=11` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on the parametrized URL the name of the parameter is `id` rather than `userId`. Model binder checks the name of the parameter to do the binding. Look on the routes definition and you'll see that.

What I mean, basically is that on the `RouteConfig.cs` file you have as the default route the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Look that the URL is `controller/action/id` and the name of the last parameter is `id`. So, in some action, to receive that piece of the URL you must match the name of the parameter.